# GCP partner interconnect configuration

Tags: google-cloud-interconnect

I'll have the following..

- 2 share vpcs (prod/non-prod)
- custom subnets in only 2 regions in each svpc

I'll have 4 circuits from my partner provider 2 for each region...how many vlan attachments should I have or do I need more circuits from the partner provider to set up partner interconnect.

Answer (score 0):

For the highest level availability, Google recommends the 99.99% availability configuration.

99.99% availability requires at least four VLAN attachments across two metros (one in each [edge availability domain](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/docs/concepts/terminology#edgeavailabilitydomain)). You also need four Cloud Routers (two in each GCP region of a VPC network). Associate one Cloud Router with each VLAN attachment. You must also enable [global routing](https://cloud.google.com/router/docs/how-to/configuring-routing-mode) for the VPC network. For more information about layer 2&3 connections please refer to documentation [1](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/docs/concepts/partner-overview) and see the example configurations.

For how to establish 99.99 & 99.9 % Availability for Partner Interconnect please refer to Tutorial [2](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/docs/tutorials/partner-creating-9999-availability) & [3](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/docs/tutorials/partner-creating-999-availability).